# Error running app on Windows Phone 8.1 emulator - A dependent dll was not found

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have universal project targeting Windows Store 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 platform.

The windows one works fine but I having trouble running the WP one on an emulator. I get the error message saying:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Unable to activate Windows Store app
>   'numbers-here!App'. The Kiss.WindowsPhone.exe process started, but the
>   activation request failed with error 'Msg in polish that the app did
>   not start'.

If this was Windows I would check System Event Log and see the logs just before the error what DLL the system was trying to load and that helped a lot when I was debugging similar problem with Windows Store project, here I have no clue on how to check what exactly was being loaded.

The worst part is that I created package (appx) and checked the dll's being packed with exe, it seems that it includes dependencies that the app explicility uses yet something is still missing and this might be some 'hidden' dependency of one of the other dlls.

Any ideas how to debug such issues with emulator?

Comment: Same problem with Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to having WIC code in my App and/or calling CoCreateInstance in a windows phone environment ( on PC it works flawlessly though )

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on Windows 10. Turns out, that there is no Kernel32.dll on Windows 10 phone!

Instead you need to link against *OneCore.lib* which provides the entire Win32 API subset that is supported in UWP. This "umbrella library" will load the correct dlls at runtime.

See also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt683763(v=vs.85).aspx